# Can a vertex lie on an edge in a planar graph?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, plane-geometry, planar-graphs

I am wondering if a vertex can lie on an edge in a planar graph- I am not sure if an edge of this vertex is regarded as crossing the edge on which the vertex lies. I have two questions here:

1. Is the actual edge from the vertex tangent to the edge on which the vertex lies?
2. Even if it only is tangent, does it still fit the definition of a planar graph that edges don't cross- as crossing would mean it would have to go through the edge and out of the edge, rather than just touching it at a single point?
3. Is a vertex simply a point and an edge a line segment in the sense in which these terms are defined in plane geometry?

Comment: By "edge on which the vertex lies" you mean edge that has this vertex as one of endpoints? And what is "actual edge" from vertex? Formally, planar graph is a graph $(V, E)$ s.t. there is embedding $V \to \mathbb R^2$, $E \to \text{curves}$ s.t. $f((v_1, v_2))$ is path from $v_1$ to $v_2$, and embeddings of different edges don't intersect. Fary's theorem says that if we require edge embeddings to be straight lines, set of planar graphs don't change. And we can easily make any two edges non-collinear by shifting vertices a bit.

Comment: A graph is planar if it has a planar embedding. This is an abstract property of the graph which is independent of how you or me draw it. So the correct question would be, if you draw it so that a vertex lies on another edge, will it be a planar embedding  - No.